# Exploring with Java streams required to read and convert the format of strings

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying Java streams to read a List of Strings, splitting the list to some format like shown below
For ex: this is in my input string -

```
[APPLE, MANGO]
```

I am trying to convert the above data to this format

```
('APPLE', 'MANGO')
```

Trying to convert this using java streams, with the below piece code

```
String.join(",", list.stream().map(item ->   "'"+item+"'").collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

The output I am getting is like below

```
('APPLE, MANGO')
```

But I am expecting like

```
('APPLE', 'MANGO')
```

Can anyone correct my java code to get above required format?

*Context to this issue is*

Trying to create a **SQL Query** like

**Select * from TEST_TABLE where ID IN ('APPLE', 'MANGO'))**

where as IN CLAUSE Parameters is an `ArrayList<String>();`

But with my code i am getting the out put as

**`Select * from TEST_TABLE where ID IN ('APPLE, MANGO'))`**

IN clause is not properly formatted , **' is missing**

Comment: You don't know what you're missing? Maybe the "splitting the list" part?

Comment: What is in `list`? It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to include a complete set of code, sample input and output, and any error messages.

Comment: The issue must be some where else. I can't reproduce. I get the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could do something like:

```
String.format("(%s)", list.stream().map(s -> String.format("'%s'", s)).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
```

EDITED:

```
String.format("%s)", list.stream().map(s -> String.format("'%s'", s)).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
```

EDITED ANOTHER TIME:

With these additional info this is what you need:

```
String query = "Select * from TEST_TABLE where ID IN (%s)"

query = String.format(query, list.stream().map(s -> String.format("'%s'", s)).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));

System.out.println(query);
```

Comment: After replacing your code, I am getting as below 
Select * from TEST_TABLE where ID IN (('APPLE, MANGO'))
But i am expecting out put like
 Select * from TEST_TABLE where ID IN ('APPLE', 'MANGO'))

Comment: Mmmmm so i'm getting you. You need a result that is placeable in a SQL "in" condition.

I edited the answer.

Comment: I edited another time. Now should work.

Comment: I tried I am getting the query like below
Select * from TEST_TABLE where ID IN ('APPLE, MANGO')

Comment: I just ran the code and my output is:

Select * from TEST_TABLE where ID IN ('APPLE','MANGO')

Comment: Could you provide the method that assembles the query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226202/discussion-between-gmhk-and-marco-dalla-santa).

Comment: that worked and there was some issues with my split logic

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
List<String> list = List.of("APPLE", "MANGO");
String sql = "Select * from TEST_TABLE where ID IN";
    
String params = list.stream().map(s -> "'" + s + "'")
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "(", ")"));
    
sql = sql + params;
System.out.println(sql);
```

I don't know if the second closing brace in your expected output was a typo or is correct. If you need a second brace just add it above.